# How do I send array with form data in vuejs

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I am developing application that I am using vuejs as frontend and laravel as backend. I am want send array through a formData but I am getting error

template

```
<template>
    <div class="__create-course">
        <section class="__header">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                <h5>Creating a course</h5>
                <button @click="createCourse" class="app_button primary_btn">Save</button>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="__body background">
            <section class="__create-course">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Course Title">Course Title</label>
                    <input placeholder="Enter course title" type="text" v-model="course.title" class="form-control x_focus">
                    <span  v-if="v$.title.$error">Title is required</span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Course Description">Course Description</label>
                    <textarea placeholder="Enter course description" name="" v-model="course.description" id="" cols="10" rows="5" class="form-control x_focus"></textarea>
                    <span  v-if="v$.description.$error">{{v$.description.$errors[0].$message}}</span>
                </div>
            
            </section>
            <section class="__course-outline">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                    <div class="pt-3">Course Outline</div>
                    <div class="__courses-created-desktop">30 Section created and files successfully upload</div>
                    <div class="__courses-created-mobile">30 Section created</div>
                </div>
            </section>
            <section class="__course-section">
                <div v-if="sections.length > 0 ">
                    <div class="__course-sub-section" v-for="(section, index) in sections" :key="index">
                    <div><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Section Title" v-model="section.section_title" class="section-title form-control x_focus"></div>
                        <div class="__upload-section d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center" v-for="(sub_section, idx) in section.sub_sections" :key="idx">
                            <div class="d-flex">
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Sub Section Title" v-model="sub_section.sub_section_title"  class="section-title form-control x_focus">
                                <div class="__choose">
                                    <label for="">
                                        <div>
                                            <input type="file" @change="uploadFile( $event, index, idx )" name="" id="">
                                            Upload File
                                        </div>
                                        <img src="@/assets/images/upload.png" alt="">
                                    </label>
                                        
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="__sub-section-image">
                                <div class="placeholder">
                                    <img :src="sub_section.url"  alt="">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                                
                            <button @click="addSubSection(index)" class="app_button primary_btn d-flex mt-4">
                                Add Sub Section
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button @click="addSection" class="app_button primary_btn d-flex mt-4">
                    Add Section
                </button>
            </section>
        </section>
    </div>
</template>
```

vuejs

In vuejs I created an array of section and an array of sub section inside section array. I want to send the data to the backend through axios but I am getting error

```
export default {
  name: 'CreateCourse',
  setup(){
      const sections = reactive([{'section_title': '', 'sub_sections': [{'sub_section_title': '', 'file': '', 'url': ''}]}]);
      const course = reactive({'title': '', 'description': ''});
      const {showLoader} = magicFunction();

  const addSection = () => {
            sections.push({"section_title": "", 'sub_sections': [{'sub_section_title': '', 'file': '', 'url': ''}]});
        }
        const addSubSection = (idx) => {
            console.log('the value of idx is ', idx);
            sections[idx].sub_sections.push({"sub_section_title": "", 'file': '', 'url': ''});
        }

        const uploadFile = (e, idx, i) => {
            sections[idx].sub_sections[i].file = e.target.files[0];
            sections[idx].sub_sections[i].url = URL.createObjectURL(sections[idx].sub_sections[i].file);

        const createCourse = (e) => {

      
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("course", course.title);
    formData.append("description", course.description);
    formData.append("section",sections[1].section_title);
        axios.post('/api', formData, { headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}}).then(response => {
            NotificationService.success(response.data.message);
            showLoader(false);
            course.title = '';
            course.description = '';
        }).catch(err => {
            NotificationService.error(err.response);
            showLoader(false);
        });
      }
        }

    return {
        course,
        createCourse,
        sections,
        addSection,
        addSubSection,
        uploadFile
    }
   }
}
```

I am getting error Uncaught TypeError: sections[1] is undefined. How do I go about this?

Comment: Hey mate, you want to send whole array or one element from array?

Comment: I want to send the hole array

Comment: Ok, `sections` is whole array , `sections[1]` is second element from that array

Comment: thank you. I tried sending sections array but i am getting error can not assign array to a string. I how do I solve the problem